# Why are Wordpress' custom CSS styles not considered on this website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

A friend created a Wordpress site and has a positioning problem with the site's header. Since he doesn't know anything about web development, I created two style declarations, which fix his problem:

```
#site-title {
    line-height: 1.1em;
}

#site-description {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

He saved those lines in Wordpress' custom style. What now happens is that those lines appear in the source code within the header tag:

```
<style id="wp-custom-css">
#site-title {
line-height: 1.1em;
}
#site-description {
margin-top: 5px;
}       </style>
```

But the browser doesn't consider those lines when rendering the site. (I also can't find those declarations within the developer console.) Why doesn't this work?

The site's domain is https://www.sabinerauscher.at

Answer (score 0):

The space between your selectors and the bracket are Unicode non-breaking spaces: %A0.

If you convert the CSS to Unicode, the two spaces are %A0 when they should be %20.

```
<style id="wp-custom-css">#site-title {line-height: 1.1em;}#site-description {margin-top: 5px;}</style>

%3Cstyle%20id%3D%22wp-custom-css%22%3E%23site-title%A0%7Bline-height%3A%201.1em%3B%7D%23site-description%A0%7Bmargin-top%3A%205px%3B%7D%3C/style%3E
```

I couldn’t find anything in the specification saying you can’t use non-breaking spaces, and the styles do show up in Firefox’s style editor, but the styles aren’t affecting the page. When I changed to regular spaces on a local copy of your page, the styles showed up.